# Why the NextPageToken in Google's StorageClient is always null?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to list all items under a path for a determined bucket using Google Cloud Storage APIs. Under this path, there are more than 1000 items - which is the maximum number of items that `ListObjects / ListObjectsAsync` return.

In order to be able to repeat the call and get the next 1000 items, I need the NextPageToken from the previous response, that's how result pagination gets done! It's easy and reasonable.

However, **I never get a NextPageToken within the responses**. Am I missing something? This is my code so far. Some key points:

1. Althought there are more than +1000 items sharing the same prefix, I only get one response while looping through them in the enumerator.
2. The NextPageToken in the `Console.WriteLine` statement is always null.
3. Repeating the same call returns the same first 1000 objects over and over.

```cs
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ListObjectsAsync(
    string prefix, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    var listObjectsOptions = new ListObjectsOptions
    {
        Fields = "items(name)"
    };

    var rawResponses = mGoogleClient.ListObjectsAsync(
        mBucketName,
        prefix,
        listObjectsOptions).AsRawResponses();

    using (var enumerator = rawResponses.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (await enumerator.MoveNext(cancelToken))
        {
            foreach (var googleObject in enumerator.Current.Items)
                yield return googleObject.Name;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.NextPageToken);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, I'm missing the `nextPageToken` field in the `ListObjectsOptions` used to make the request. Without specifying that field, the service won't return it - because of who knows why!

This code should work:

```cs
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ListObjectsAsync(
    string prefix, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    var listObjectsOptions = new ListObjectsOptions
    {
        Fields = "items(name),nextPageToken"
    };

    var rawResponses = mGoogleClient.ListObjectsAsync(
        mBucketName,
        prefix,
        listObjectsOptions).AsRawResponses();

    using (var enumerator = rawResponses.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (await enumerator.MoveNext(cancelToken))
        {
            foreach (var googleObject in enumerator.Current.Items)
                yield return googleObject.Name;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.NextPageToken);
    }
}
```

The nice thing is that you don't even have to use the `NextPageToken` explicitly. This is, you **don't** have to do something like this:

```cs
string token = null;
do
{
    var options = new ListObjectsOptions
    {
        Fields = "items(name),nextPageToken",
        PageToen = token
    };

    var rawResponses = mGoogleClient.ListObjectsAsync(
        mBucketName,
        prefix,
        listObjectsOptions).AsRawResponses();

    using (var enumerator = rawResponses.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (await enumerator.MoveNext(cancelToken))
        {
            foreach (var googleObject in enumerator.Current.Items)
                yield return googleObject.Name;
        }

        token = enumerator.Current.NextPageToken;
    }
}
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token));
```

...because the enumerator you got in `rawResponses.GetEnumerator()` will take care of using the token of a response to automatically fetch the next (if needed) while iterating them.

So the first piece of code is valid to iterate over +1000 objects in a single call.